How to use "_exists" operator in Hasura's Logical Model per row level permission for a Native Query?
I'm trying to add advanced "row select level permission" rules in a Logical Model for a Native Query in Hasura, but Hasura Console (Web GUI) panel shows less options in comparison to the regular table based "row select level permission".
The options I'm missing is the "_exists" and "_table" operators.
When trying to copy the table based permission into the logical model permission, the permission panel is not updated:

And this is the table based permission:

This is more or less the permission I'm trying to use:
{
      "_exists": {
        "_table": {
          "name": "validation_table",
          "schema": "main"
        },
        "_where": {
          "_and": [
            { "account_id": { "_eq": "x-hasura-account-id" } },
            { "hasura_role": { "_eq": "x-hasura-role" } },
            { "operation_type": { "_eq": "select" } },
            { "validation_table_specific_column": { "_ceq": ["$", "logical_model_specific_column"]}}
          ]
        }
      }
}

When trying to save the permissions Hasura Console throws the following errors:
Inconsistent object: table "main.validation_table" has no field named "validation_table_specific_column"

Which is incorrect because validation_table_specific_column exists in main.validation_table.
I'm using Hasura v2.36.1-ce
Is Hasura missing _exists and _table operators for Logical Models or am I missing something?
